# Simple Angular script not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a super simple angular app at [This Weaver](http://liveweave.com/nvTEBw), but it's not working. What's the problem? I've got a link to angular, and I've set everything up. Why's it not working?

Comment: Where's your JS code?

Comment: @Leshy i suggest you to read the following tutorial: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AliGajani it's at the link, along with HTML.

Comment: @Romulo That's what I did. I cut out all unnescessary code, and provided a link to it.

Comment: Questions should be self contained. Links rot rendering question useless in the future and we shouldn't have to go off site to see what your problem is

Comment: @charlietfl I'm sorry I figured it would be easier this way because you can play around with the code instead of just viewing it. Also, I wasn't sure if the 'embed code' option on the ask a question page would like my link to angular

Comment: It's up to you if you want help. Rules are pretty simple... post the relevant code. It's not about how simple it is for you ... you are the one asking for help, not us

Comment: @charlietfl I want help which is why I tried to make it easy for you to help by posting it somewhere that you can play around with it. Haven't you seen how many questions include a link to JSFiddle?

Comment: demo is helpful, but as support for the question. These questions will live for years and links rot. If you have looked at other questions then you know they all include code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LiveWeave sucks use  plunker.  Here it is working on live weave but you have to refresh](http://liveweave.com/emQ3lt)

script.js -

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrlr', ['$scope', function ($scope){
  $scope.hello = "hello world";
}]);
```

index.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.3.6" data-semver="1.3.6" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrlr">
    <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

[here is a simple angularjs app in plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HWG48civ9vzNO50IGLo3?p=preview)